# decoding URL in JS not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have this url that im trying to decode

```
var a = 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gem.com%2Fextension%3Furl%3D'
var b = decodeURI(a)
console.log(b)
```

> "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gem.com%2Fextension%3Furl%3D"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```js
var a = 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gem.com%2Fextension%3Furl%3D';
var b = decodeURIComponent(a);
console.log(b);
```